# Place footnote in footer in Tufte-book class

Tags: header-footer, footnotes, tufte

Good morning to everyone, I'm new to the forum and use very little Latex. So sorry if the question is silly. I created a text using tufte-book class and I like how it places the images and sidenotes but I would like to place some footnotes, not to the side, but in the classic footer position. I saw that tufte-class is not compatible with footmisc. How can I do? thanks

Answer (score 6):

The source of the Tufte classes says:

```
% Transform existing \footnotes into \sidenotes
% Sidenote: ``Where God meant footnotes to go.'' ---Tufte
```

That explains why `tufte-book` is incompatible with `footmisc` and why its footnotes are sidenotes.

That said, we can workaround this. But I'll tell you, it's a low blow.

We can copy the definition of the `\footnote` command and friends from `latex.ltx` and make a package out of it. Then just include this package in your tufte-book and you're good to go.

The package file `tuftefoot.sty`:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/12/01]
\ProvidesPackage{tuftefoot}[2018/02/27 v0.1 Footnotes for tufte-book class]
\newinsert\footins
\skip\footins=\bigskipamount % space added when footnote is present
\count\footins=1000 % footnote magnification factor (1 to 1)
\dimen\footins=8in % maximum footnotes per page
\def\TFfootnoterule{\kern-3\p@
  \hrule \@width 2in \kern 2.6\p@} % the \hrule is .4pt high
\@definecounter{footnote}
\def\TFthefootnote{\@arabic\c@footnote}
\@definecounter{mpfootnote}
\def\TFthempfootnote{{\itshape\@alph\c@mpfootnote}}
\def\TF@makefnmark{\hbox{\TF@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}}
\DeclareRobustCommand*\textsuperscript[1]{%
  \TF@textsuperscript{\selectfont#1}}
\def\TF@textsuperscript#1{%
  {\m@th\ensuremath{^{\mbox{\fontsize\sf@size\z@#1}}}}}
\DeclareRobustCommand*\textsubscript[1]{%
  \TF@textsubscript{\selectfont#1}}%
\def\TF@textsubscript#1{%
  {\m@th\ensuremath{_{\mbox{\fontsize\sf@size\z@#1}}}}}%
\def\TF@textsubscript#1{%
  {\m@th\ensuremath{_{\mbox{\fontsize\sf@size\z@#1}}}}}
\newdimen\TFfootnotesep
\def\TFfootnote{\@ifnextchar[\TF@xfootnote{\stepcounter\TF@mpfn
     \protected@xdef\@thefnmark{\TFthempfn}%
     \TF@footnotemark\TF@footnotetext}}
\def\TF@xfootnote[#1]{%
   \begingroup
     \csname c@\TF@mpfn\endcsname #1\relax
     \unrestored@protected@xdef\@thefnmark{\TFthempfn}%
   \endgroup
   \TF@footnotemark\TF@footnotetext}
\long\def\TF@footnotetext#1{\insert\footins{%
    \reset@font\footnotesize
    \interlinepenalty\interfootnotelinepenalty
    \splittopskip\TFfootnotesep
    \splitmaxdepth \dp\strutbox \floatingpenalty \@MM
    \hsize\columnwidth \@parboxrestore
    \protected@edef\@currentlabel{%
       \csname p@footnote\endcsname\@thefnmark
    }%
    \color@begingroup
      \@makefntext{%
        \rule\z@\TFfootnotesep\ignorespaces#1\@finalstrut\strutbox}%
    \color@endgroup}}%
\def\TFfootnotemark{%
   \@ifnextchar[\TF@xfootnotemark
     {\stepcounter{footnote}%
      \protected@xdef\@thefnmark{\TFthefootnote}%
      \TF@footnotemark}}
\def\TF@xfootnotemark[#1]{%
   \begingroup
      \c@footnote #1\relax
      \unrestored@protected@xdef\@thefnmark{\TFthefootnote}%
   \endgroup
   \TF@footnotemark}
\def\TF@footnotemark{%
  \leavevmode
  \ifhmode\edef\@x@sf{\the\spacefactor}\nobreak\fi
  \TF@makefnmark
  \ifhmode\spacefactor\@x@sf\fi
  \relax}
\def\TFfootnotetext{%
     \@ifnextchar [\TF@xfootnotenext
       {\protected@xdef\@thefnmark{\TFthempfn}%
    \TF@footnotetext}}
\def\TF@xfootnotenext[#1]{%
  \begingroup
     \csname c@\TF@mpfn\endcsname #1\relax
     \unrestored@protected@xdef\@thefnmark{\TFthempfn}%
  \endgroup
  \TF@footnotetext}
\def\TF@mpfn{footnote}
\def\TFthempfn{\TFthefootnote}
```

I renamed all instances of `\footnote` to `\TFfootnote`, `\footnotemark` to `\TFfootnotemark`, and so on, to avoid conflict.

To use it, just save the code above as `tuftefoot.sty`. To use it is quite simple:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{tuftefoot}

\begin{document}

Some dummy text.\TFfootnotemark
\TFfootnotetext{\label{fn1}With some footnote.}

More dummy text.\TFfootnote{\label{fn2}With more footnote.}

See footnotes~\ref{fn1} and~\ref{fn2}. They are important.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like it very much, except \setcounter{footnote}{-1} is needed to start footnotes at 1.

Comment: @jlettvin Not normally;  I just tried the example in the answer and `\setcounter` is not needed.  There must be something else that is changing your footnote counter.  You can [ask a question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) with a compilable example that shows the problem.

Comment: TNX.  I will construct a MWE, I hope.